# Difference between ngModules and index.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-seed

I have been looking at [angular seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed) and I am wondering why do they use both `index.ts` and modules. 
from my understanding, they can both be used to export typescript types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two are entirely unrelated.

index.ts is for TypeScript imports. You need these whenever you use an identifier in a typescript file that is declared in another typescript file.

`NgModule` is to register directives, components, pipes, and providers in other `NgModule`s.

Comment: so, let's say I have a component, that I only use in my html - it needs to be in a module and not `index.ts`?

Comment: You don't **need** to use `index.ts` at all. You can also import directly from the file where an identifier is defined. `index.ts` are just for convenience because they make it easier to import several identifiers at once.

If you don't refer a components class, you don't need TypeScript imports. If you want to use a component you need it to `declarations` of `NgModule`. To be able to do that you need a TypeScript import, except when the component and the `NgModule` are in the same file.